# What roles are allowed to see the credentials in VCAP_SERVICES?

Tags: authentication, ibm-cloud, user-roles

When managing the roles in a Bluemix space, I see that there are check boxes for `manager`, `developer` and `auditor`. I'd like to understand what roles can see the full `VCAP_SERVICES` contents and what have the credentials blanked out. E.g.,

```
{
    "speech_to_text": [
        {
            "name": "Speech To Text-7o",
            "label": "speech_to_text",
            "plan": "standard",
            "credentials": {
                "redacted_message": "[PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN]"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Manager and developer roles are able to access `VCAP_SERVICES`, but not auditor. To my understanding, it is all or nothing (no partially redacted or obscured fields).

Comment: I was added to an organization and the text I pasted is part of what I was seeing when I looked at the environment of an app that was already running before I joined.

Comment: In what role were you added?

Comment: The only check box that was set was "manager". In case it matters, the organization was one of those that are associated to another user's account.